# How to assign, change and remove category from sent email?

Tags: vba, outlook

I send emails that I don't get any reply to. I need to keep track of this to send a follow-up email.

I want a macro that does the following:

1. Before sending an email, I set a reminder with the follow-up flag. This way, I can choose a custom time to follow up on this specific email.
2. If the sent email is marked with a follow-up flag it is automatically marked with category "blue".
3. If I get a reply before the timer I set, the task is cleared and the blue category is cleared.
4. If I don't get a reply before the timer runs out, the category changes to red and I get a notification reminder from Outlook.

This way I can sort my "sent" folder to the two categories to see what emails need follow up. Moreover, I get a reminder each time people don't respond in time.

The below code clears the follow-up flag if I received a reply within the set time.
I don't know how to assign a category to the sent item and to clear it.

```vb
Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInboxItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

'If receive the reply, clear the flag and remove the reminder
Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objSentItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim objVariant As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim dSendTime As String
 
    Set objSentItems = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
 
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
       For i = 1 To objSentItems.Count
           If objSentItems.Item(i).Class = olMail Then
              Set objVariant = objSentItems.Item(i)
              strSubject = LCase(objVariant.Subject)
              dSendTime = objVariant.SentOn
 
              If LCase(Item.Subject) = "re: " & strSubject Or InStr(LCase(Item.Subject), strSubject) > 0 Then
                 If Item.SentOn > dSendTime Then
                    With objVariant
                         .ClearTaskFlag
                         .ReminderSet = False
                         .Save
                    End With
                    
                 End If
              End If
           End If
       Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a class I used some time ago. Maybe you can grab some ideas

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "ThisOutlookSession"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Option Explicit
'Categorize Sent Items
'Place in ThisOutlookSession
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next

Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim stringCatReference() As Variant


stringCatReference = Array("CAM-", "CGI-", "COS-", "CON-", "HEXA-", "ITH-", "KALL-")

    If TypeOf Application.ActiveWindow Is Outlook.Inspector Then
        Set insp = Application.ActiveWindow
    End If
    
    If insp Is Nothing Then
        Dim inline As Object
        Set inline = Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse
        If inline Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Else
       Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector
       If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
          
       Else
         Exit Sub
       End If

    End If
    
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem And IsInArray(Item.Subject, stringCatReference) = 0 Then
        Set Item = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        Item.ShowCategoriesDialog
        Item.Save
    End If
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    
    Dim xInt As Integer
    
    For xInt = 0 To UBound(arr)
    
        IsInArray = InStr(stringToBeFound, arr(xInt)) > 0
        
        If IsInArray = True Then Exit For
        
    Next xInt

End Function
```